# Python: Need help importing module from a different directory

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-module

I'm running Python3.6 on Mac OSX 10.12.4

```
/Documents/PyProjects/modules/
```

In that directory, resides `__init__.py` and Pyrime.py. Pyrime.py has some functions in it.

```
/Documents/PyProjects/PE010/
```

In that directory resides my program: `PE010_Summation_of_Primes.py`. I want to import one function, called `is_prime`, in `Pyrime.py` to use in `PE010_Summation_of_Primes.py`. I thought all I would need to do is write, in `PE010_Summation_of_Primes.py`:

```
from modules.Pyrime import is_prime
```

This doesn't work. My terminal throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PE010_Summation_of_Primes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Pyrime import is_prime
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pyrime'
```

Python is the first language I've ever seen, and I've only seen it for about a week so far. I've looked at a lot of documentation, but for a beginner like me, it hasn't been very enlightening.

Comment: For sure have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) the basics are described pretty clear. One of the things to comment on in your description is that you'll have to respect the name `__init__.py` (mind the two double underscores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the system-path at runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/py_file')
import py_file
```

it will work!

Comment: This worked! And after reading some more documentation, I think I understand it!. Thank you so much!

Comment: Most Welcome ! (y)

Answer (score 1):

Well, python refers the global library directory or local directory when trying to import a file. But for files in directories other than local you can either add file path to `sys.path` or create a `__init__.py` file in all directories including the parent directory `PyProjects`. Try this -

`from modules.Pyrime import is_prime`

So your directory will look something like this -

```
PyProjects
    -- __init__.py
    -- PE010
        -- __init__.py
        -- PE010_Summation_of_Primes.py
    -- modules
        -- __init__.py
        -- Pyrime.py
```

Hope it helps.